# Getting error in Deposit function in smart contract : The constructor should be payable if you send value

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

I am getting the error while deposit the amount in remix.

Following is my code

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

 contract Savings {
 address owner;
 uint256 deadline;

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable {
    require(msg.value == amount);
}

function Savings(uint256 numberOfDays) public payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
    deadline = now + (numberOfDays * 1 days);
}

function withdraw() public onlyOwner  {
    require(now >= deadline);

    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into remix and tried depositing. seems to work fine.
If I am not entering the value in the field, I am able to observe the error you observed. Please check if you have added the amount in wei.

Comment: Yes, It works for me as well thanks for your time

Comment: you are welcome :)